# Получить файл с удаленного компьютера

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, советом.

Есть приложение, установленное на машине, машина расшариная, то есть в другой машины в данной сети можно запустить приложение по ip-адресу.

У меня на главной странице есть форма, куда необходимо передать excel файл. Но загвоздка во в чем, когда на стороне java я обрабатываю файл, естественно он просит, чтобы файл был в том каталоге откуда запускается приложение, то есть абсолютный путь, он как раз есть рабочая машина, на которой установлен томкат, и откуда он запущен. Если файл положить в каталог томката/bin, то все работает прекрасно, стоит загрузить файл например с рабоче стола, то он ругается, что файл не найден, а уж с удаленной машине и подавно не загрузить.

Пожалуйста, дайте совет, как это можно реализовать, я пытался подменять через JS путь на c:\fakepath\имя файла, но это не сработало, на  macOS тем более.

Сам файл загружаю при помощи AJAX и далее к контроллере просто принимаю его как тип File. и уже передаю в метод, где его разбираю.

Файл js

```
function calcGroupRate() {
var file = checkEmpty($('input[name="ratesGroupFile"]')
  .val().split("\\").pop());
  $.ajax({
    url: "rate/group",
    datatype: "json",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ file: file })
  });
 }
```

Контроллер java

```
@PostMapping(value = "/group")
public ResponseEntity<Object> totalGroupModel(@RequestBody CalcGroupRateBody object) {
    logger.info(object.getFile().getPath());
    logger.info(object.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    logger.info(object.getFile().getName());
    groupCalculateRate.fetchGroupModels(object.getFile());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(groupCalculateRate.getListError(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Далее файл передаю в другой класс где разбираю Эксель

```
public List<GroupListBasicDate> getGroupListBasicDateFromFile(File file) {
    try {
        XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

Comment: я не смог из Вашего описания понять что вы в итоге пытаетесь получить

Comment: Покажите код, в котором ищется файл, мне кажется проблема в нем. А ещё в ОС есть переменные окружения, вот например, как получить рабочий стол `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";`

Comment: а ещё после диска надо 2 разделителя между папками `new File("C:\\example");` А ещё лучше пользоваться переменной `File.separator` для разделения

Comment: @StrangerintheQ чтобы web-приложение смогло обработать полученный файл. То есть, есть машина, рядом еще одна, вот на одной запущен томкат и установлено web-приложение. Я на другой. браузере по ip адресу вызывают web-приложение. Оно запускает, но когда я пытаюсь загрузить файл в этом приложение, он естественно ругается, что файла такого нет. так как проверяет его в каталоге томката. Вот каким образом можно это решить, чтобы файл без проблем обработался переданного с соседнего пк

Comment: то есть с компьютера на котором открыто веб приложение передать файл для обработки на сервер?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ наоборот, с соседнего ПК. На котором как раз нет не томката не приложения.

Comment: приложите к вопросу код веб страницы и код сервера, относящийся к указанной проблеме

Comment: @CyberDoge По поводу загрузки файла локально, проблем нет. Мне важно как получить файл с удаленного ПК

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил код, там особо ничего нет, обычный процесс загрузки.

Comment: ну вы же не приняли файл, а только узнали как он называется

Comment: @StrangerintheQ почему я не принял? сейчас же в XSSFWorkbook можно передать прям file, а не ImputStream.

Comment: сохраните файл на диск, а потом работайте с ним

Comment: @StrangerintheQ зачем его сохранять на диск? То есть в какой момент его сохранить? Мне же надо с соседнего ПК передать файл, у меня же эксепшен выскакивает что файл не найден.

Comment: файл у вас через js приходит проверяли? object.getFile() непустой?

Comment: Чтобы передать файл надо использовать тип блоб.

Comment: @dSH да, я по нему информацию получаю, но это если я его положу как раз в директорию, из которой запускаю томкат. Если положу его например на рабочий стол, то получу эксепшен что файл не найден. Но я тут поэкспериментировал и понял, что надо передавать его enctype multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос небольшим хаком. 
Путем пересоздания файла в темповой папке томката и уже его забирать. Можно сказать, как подсказал @StrangerintheQ.

```
private static File convertToFile;

public static File multipartToFile(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        convertToFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), file.getOriginalFilename());
        convertToFile.createNewFile();
        try(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(convertToFile)) {
            fileOutputStream.write(file.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Ошибка конвертации файла - {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return convertToFile;
}
```

Comment: теперь вы поняли, что я имел в виду про принять? вам нужно вручную произвести процедуру чтения из сокета и записи в файл, это особенность реализации poi, как я понял - работа именно с файлом, у меня не было возможности поотестировать, по этому я не стал писать развернутый ответ

Comment: вероятно это связано с тем что файл может быть большой и в этом случае, poi, чтобы обращаться к разным частям, во время работы не загружает его сразу, или двигается по нему вперед-назад, с сетевым inputstream такое вряд ли возможно

Comment: да, спасибо большое, только тут в ответе я не отразил чтение-запись. Ну смысл ясен